# Matrix class proxy for operator [] error

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading, stdvector

So, I have such classes: `Matrix` and `Matrix_Proxy`. Both should check if range is valid, but here I ommited that because that is not the problem.

As long as objects are non-const, it's fine, but that won't do. Sending function parameters by `const&` is effective practice, and so here it fails.

The code (simplified):

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Matrix_Proxy
{
public:
    Matrix_Proxy(std::vector<T>& _ref, size_t _size) : ref(_ref), size(_size)
    {}
    T& operator[](int i)
    {
        return ref[i];
    }

    const T& operator[](int i) const
    {
        return ref[i];
    }

private:
    std::vector<T>& ref;
    size_t size;

};

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(size_t x) : values(x), size(x)
    {
        for(auto&& y : values)
        {
            y.resize(x);
            for(auto&& x : y)
                x = 0;
        }
    }

    Matrix_Proxy<T> operator [] (int i)
    {
        return Matrix_Proxy<T>(values[i],size);
    }

    const Matrix_Proxy<T> operator [] (int i) const
    {
        return Matrix_Proxy<T>(values[i],size);
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> values;
    size_t size;
};

int main()
{
    Matrix<int> intMat(5);                    //FINE
    std::cout << intMat[2][2] << std::endl;   //FINE

    const Matrix<int> cintMat(5);             //FINE
    std::cout << cintMat[2][2] << std::endl;  //ERROR

    _Exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Error:

```
no matching function for call to 'Matrix_Proxy<int>::Matrix_Proxy(const value_type&, const size_t&)'
         return Matrix_Proxy<T>(values[i],size);
                                              ^
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is that your proxy allows for non-const access, even if the proxy itself has been produced through a `const` operator. In other words, your code, if it could compile, would allow for this:

```
const Matrix<int> cintMat(5);
cintMat[2][2] = 2; // Does not compile
```

This is because `Matrix_Proxy` produced from `operator [] const` has both `operator [] const` and `operator []` non-const. Your `Matrix_Proxy` has no idea that it has been produced through a `const` operator!

To fix this problem, introduce another proxy, and return it from the `const` operator `[]`:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix_Proxy_Const
{
public:
    Matrix_Proxy_Const(const std::vector<T>& _ref, size_t _size) : ref(_ref), size(_size)
    {}
    const T& operator[](int i) const {
        return ref[i];
    }
private:
    const std::vector<T>& ref;
    size_t size;
};
```

In the `Matrix` class change the `const` operator implementation:

```
const Matrix_Proxy_Const<T> operator [] (int i) const {
    return Matrix_Proxy_Const<T>(values[i],size);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/HmlLfU)

Comment: Wow, everything is perfect now :) But i still got owned by std::vector<bool>, but well, that can't be helped. Thanks :)